# How to return [Table].[Column] in SQL MS results to grid

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Say I am querying multiple tables like so

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.* FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ... etc.
```

In SQL Server Management Studio, I want the results to show in the grid with the table names prepended to the column names

What I get by default is this:

> ID | A1 | ... | ID | B1

But I want this:

> T1.ID | T1.A1 | ... | T2.ID | T2.B1

Is there any command or setting which will make the table names be displayed in the results grid?

(There are many columns, so I want to use the *. I am not looking to ask for the columns individually).

Comment: No there is no way to do that without jumping through hoops. Since this sounds like you are doing development and trying to determine which table columns belong to as you flush out your query you could add a constant column as a visual divider. t1.*, '-----' as Divider, t2.*

Comment: @SeanLange That's exactly what I do now. But it still gets confusing when looking back and forth at a lot of data in different grids. Thanks.

Comment: The pseudocode I posted would let you keep the results in a single grid but with a visual queue of a bunch of dashes in a column to help visualize which table you are in. That make sense?

Comment: If the columns don't fit in one grid, you need to scroll around to see that queue, for instance. Yes this is how I manage now. I was just hoping there was a better way but from a lack of answers, it seems not.

Comment: Not unless you create two queries so it would produce two result sets. 1 for each table you want to evaluate.